# Add special comment to the tags

Tags: discussion, tags

My question is related to [this Q/A](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7188/34947).

In Photo.SE there are tags, related to legal part of photography like **legal**, **copyright**, **model-releases** and so on. Is it appropriate to add in those tags clarification as it is in Law.SE?
The text I have in mind can be like this:

> Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a
> substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal
> practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged
> communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be overkill. If people don't understand they shouldn't believe things they read on the Internet without verifying them, that's not a problem which is going to be solved by a disclaimer on a tag. To some extent, this reflects [this answer from Jeff himself](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/720/11371).

Also as a practical point, this disclaimer wouldn't really fit into the tag excerpts and to a very good approximation nobody reads the tag wiki entries - this is why Law (and other similar sites e.g. [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)) have to put their disclaimers into the site style itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is more a concern on law where there are lawyers on it.  There is an implication that something a lawyer says might be legal advice, so it covers their rear to state it is not.  As people who are not lawyers, it would be much harder for someone to argue we were giving legal advice, so it's probably less necessary.  At least that's my understanding of it.